# Differences between model results

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I've been experimenting with VAEs for weeks now, trying to get similar results as in a tutorial code, but being unsuccessful in it. The only difference between mine and the tutorial's code is that it compiles the model (demonstration will be below), and runs fit on it, but I run each layer manually. What I've done is set up weight initialization with numpy arrays, just as with epsilons, saved into .npy files, and ran the two models. The results were different (the tutorial's model gives way more smooth results)

As of my understanding of neural networks so far, given the same training data in the same order, with the same layers, with same initial weights, same optimizer, and hyperparameters, the results should be the same all the time.

I've made 3 simple examples. MNIST data with two dense layers with sizes 16, and 10. Weight initialization:

```
import numpy as np

w1 = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(784, 16))
w2 = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(16, 10))

np.save('w1', w1)
np.save('w2', w2)
```

First version (manually executing layers):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import math

w1 = np.load('w1.npy')
w2 = np.load('w2.npy')

class Model(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.flat = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
    self.w1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
      units=16,
      activation='relu',
      use_bias=False,
      kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(w1)
    )
    self.w2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
      units=10,
      activation='sigmoid',
      use_bias=False,
      kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(w2)
    )
    self.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
  
  @tf.function
  def call(self, x, y):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      x = self.flat(x)
      a = self.w1(x)
      y_hat = self.w2(a)

      loss = tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y, y_hat)

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.trainable_variables)
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.trainable_variables))

    return loss

def train(x, y, epochs, batch_size):
  batch_quantity = math.floor(x.shape[0] / batch_size)

  for e in range(epochs):
    for b in range(batch_quantity):
      train_x = x[b:b + batch_size]
      train_y = y[b:b + batch_size]

      loss = model(train_x, train_y)

      print(
        'Epoch:', e,
        'Batch:', b,
        'Loss:', loss.numpy().sum(),
      )

model = Model()

(x, y), _ = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

epochs = 30
batch_size = 100

train(x, y, epochs, batch_size)
```

This one gives the exact same results no matter how many times you run it. As expected.

Second version (saving layers into a Model - manually calculating gradients, optimization - compile, and fit):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

w1 = np.load('w1.npy')
w2 = np.load('w2.npy')

input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(28, 28))
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(input)
a = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
  units=16,
  activation='relu',
  use_bias=False,
  kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(w1)
)(x)
y_hat = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
  units=10,
  activation='sigmoid',
  use_bias=False,
  kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(w2)
)(a)
model = tf.keras.Model(input, y_hat, name='model')
model.summary()

class Model(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, model):
    super().__init__()
    self.model = model

  def train_step(self, data):
    x, y = data[0]
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      y_hat = self.model(x)

      loss = tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y, y_hat)

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.trainable_variables)
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.trainable_variables))

    return {
      'loss': tf.reduce_sum(loss)
    }

model = Model(model)

train_data, _ = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

epochs = 30
batch_size = 100

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())
model.fit(train_data, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size shuffle=False)
```

Third version (saving layers into a Model compile, and fit):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

w1 = np.load('w1.npy')
w2 = np.load('w2.npy')

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(
    units=16,
    activation='relu',
    use_bias=False,
    kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(w1)
  ),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(
    units=10,
    activation='sigmoid',
    use_bias=False,
    kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(w2)
  )
])

(x, y), _ = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

batch_size = 100
epochs = 30

model.compile(
  loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.SUM),
  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
)

model.fit(
  x, y, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, shuffle=False
)
```

The second, and third versions are giving almost the exact same results, but different than the first. That I can't understand, as the optimizer, the loss function, the loss reduction, initial weights, training data, everything is exactly the same.

If you're curious, the VAE examples, and their differences can be tested.
Initialize weights:

```
import numpy as np

epsilon = np.random.normal(size=(100, 2))

wc1 = np.random.uniform(-0.022, 0.022, size=(3,3,1,32))
wc2 = np.random.uniform(-0.022, 0.022, size=(3,3,32,64))
wd1 = np.random.uniform(-0.022, 0.022, size=(3136,16))
wm = np.random.uniform(-0.022, 0.022, size=(16,2))
ws = np.random.uniform(-0.022, 0.022, size=(16,2))
wd2 = np.random.uniform(-0.022, 0.022, size=(2,3136))
wct1 = np.random.uniform(-0.022, 0.022, size=(3,3,64,64))
wct2 = np.random.uniform(-0.022, 0.022, size=(3,3,32,64))
wct3 = np.random.uniform(-0.022, 0.022, size=(3,3,1,32))

np.save('epsilon', epsilon)

np.save('wc1', wc1)
np.save('wc2', wc2)
np.save('wd1', wd1)
np.save('wm', wm)
np.save('ws', ws)
np.save('wd2', wd2)
np.save('wct1', wct1)
np.save('wct2', wct2)
np.save('wct3', wct3)
```

Tutorial's VAE:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

wc1 = np.load('wc1.npy')
wc2 = np.load('wc2.npy')
wd1 = np.load('wd1.npy')
wm = np.load('wm.npy')
ws = np.load('ws.npy')
wd2 = np.load('wd2.npy')
wct1 = np.load('wct1.npy')
wct2 = np.load('wct2.npy')
wct3 = np.load('wct3.npy')
epsilon = np.load('epsilon.npy')

class Sampling(layers.Layer):
    """Uses (z_mean, z_log_var) to sample z, the vector encoding a digit."""

    def call(self, inputs):
        z_mean, z_log_var = inputs
        # batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
        # dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
        # epsilon = tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
        return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon

latent_dim = 2

encoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same", use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(wc1))(encoder_inputs)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same", use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(wc2))(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(16, activation="relu", use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(wd1))(x)
z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_mean", use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(wm))(x)
z_log_var = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_log_var", use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(ws))(x)
z = Sampling()([z_mean, z_log_var])
encoder = keras.Model(encoder_inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name="encoder")
encoder.summary()

latent_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
x = layers.Dense(7 * 7 * 64, activation="relu", use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(wd2))(latent_inputs)
x = layers.Reshape((7, 7, 64))(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same", use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(wct1))(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same", use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(wct2))(x)
decoder_outputs = layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, 3, activation="sigmoid", padding="same", use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(wct3))(x)
decoder = keras.Model(latent_inputs, decoder_outputs, name="decoder")
decoder.summary()

class VAE(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, **kwargs):
        super(VAE, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder

    def train_step(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, tuple):
            data = data[0]
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            z_mean, z_log_var, z = encoder(data)
            reconstruction = decoder(z)
            reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction)
            )
            reconstruction_loss *= 28 * 28
            kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var)
            kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(kl_loss)
            kl_loss *= -0.5
            total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss

        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))
        return {
            'mean': z_mean,
            "loss": total_loss,
            "reconstruction_loss": reconstruction_loss,
            "kl_loss": kl_loss,
        }

(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
mnist_digits = x_train
mnist_digits = np.expand_dims(mnist_digits, -1).astype("float32") / 255

epochs=30
batch_size=100

vae = VAE(encoder, decoder)
vae.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())
vae.fit(mnist_digits, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_latent(encoder, decoder):
    # display a n*n 2D manifold of digits
    n = 30
    digit_size = 28
    scale = 2.0
    figsize = 15
    figure = np.zeros((digit_size * n, digit_size * n))
    # linearly spaced coordinates corresponding to the 2D plot
    # of digit classes in the latent space
    grid_x = np.linspace(-scale, scale, n)
    grid_y = np.linspace(-scale, scale, n)[::-1]

    for i, yi in enumerate(grid_y):
        for j, xi in enumerate(grid_x):
            z_sample = np.array([[xi, yi]])
            x_decoded = decoder.predict(z_sample)
            digit = x_decoded[0].reshape(digit_size, digit_size)
            figure[
                i * digit_size : (i + 1) * digit_size,
                j * digit_size : (j + 1) * digit_size,
            ] = digit

    plt.figure(figsize=(figsize, figsize))
    start_range = digit_size // 2
    end_range = n * digit_size + start_range + 1
    pixel_range = np.arange(start_range, end_range, digit_size)
    sample_range_x = np.round(grid_x, 1)
    sample_range_y = np.round(grid_y, 1)
    plt.xticks(pixel_range, sample_range_x)
    plt.yticks(pixel_range, sample_range_y)
    plt.xlabel("z[0]")
    plt.ylabel("z[1]")
    plt.imshow(figure, cmap="Greys_r")
    plt.savefig('trg.png')
    plt.close()


plot_latent(encoder, decoder)

def plot_label_clusters(encoder, decoder, data, labels):
    # display a 2D plot of the digit classes in the latent space
    z_mean, _, _ = encoder.predict(data)
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))
    plt.scatter(z_mean[:, 0], z_mean[:, 1], c=labels)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.xlabel("z[0]")
    plt.ylabel("z[1]")
    plt.savefig('wer.png')
    plt.close()


(x_train, y_train), _ = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1).astype("float32") / 255

plot_label_clusters(encoder, decoder, x_train, y_train)
```

My VAE:

```
import math
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

batch_size = 100
epochs = 30

(x, y), _ = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x = tf.expand_dims(x.astype("float32") / 255, 3)

wc1 = np.load('wc1.npy')
wc2 = np.load('wc2.npy')
wd1 = np.load('wd1.npy')
wm = np.load('wm.npy')
ws = np.load('ws.npy')
wd2 = np.load('wd2.npy')
wct1 = np.load('wct1.npy')
wct2 = np.load('wct2.npy')
wct3 = np.load('wct3.npy')
epsilon = np.load('epsilon.npy')

class VAE(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.encoder = [
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same", use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(wc1)),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same", use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(wc2)),
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu", use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(wd1)),
    ]
    self.wm = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(wm))
    self.wv = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(ws))
    self.decoder = [
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(7 * 7 * 64, activation="relu", use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(wd2)),
      tf.keras.layers.Reshape((7, 7, 64)),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same", use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(wct1)),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same", use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(wct2)),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, 3, activation="sigmoid", padding="same", use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(wct3)),
    ]
    self.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

  @tf.function
  def call(self, x):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      z = x
      for layer in self.encoder:
        z = layer(z)

      mean = self.wm(z)
      stdev = self.wv(z)
      # epsilon = tf.random.normal(mean.shape)
      z = mean + tf.exp(0.5 * stdev) * epsilon

      y_pred = z
      for layer in self.decoder:
        y_pred = layer(y_pred)

      reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(x, y_pred)
      )
      reconstruction_loss *= 28 * 28
      kl_loss = 1 + stdev - tf.square(mean) - tf.exp(stdev)
      kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(kl_loss)
      kl_loss *= -0.5
      loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.trainable_weights)
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.trainable_weights))

    return loss, reconstruction_loss, kl_loss

model = VAE()

def train(x):
  batch_quantity = math.floor(x.shape[0] / batch_size)

  for i in range(epochs):
    for bi in range(batch_quantity):
      train_x = x[bi:bi + batch_size]

      loss, reconstruction_loss, kl_loss = model(train_x)

      print(
        'Epoch:', i,
        'Batch:', bi,
        'Loss:', loss.numpy(),
        'Reconstruction:', reconstruction_loss.numpy(),
        'KL:', kl_loss.numpy()
      )

train(x)

# display a 2D plot of the digit classes in the latent space
z = x
for layer in model.encoder:
  z = layer(z)
mean = model.wm(z)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))
plt.scatter(mean[:, 0], mean[:, 1], c=y)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("z[0]")
plt.ylabel("z[1]")
plt.savefig('def.png')
plt.close()

n = 30
d = 2.0
s = 28
grid_x = np.linspace(-d, d, n)
grid_y = np.linspace(d, -d, n)

image_width = s*n
image_height = image_width
image = np.zeros((image_height, image_width))

for row, x in enumerate(grid_x):
  for col, y in enumerate(grid_y):
    z = np.array([[x, y]])
    for layer in model.decoder:
      z = layer(z)
    digit = tf.squeeze(z)
    image[row * s: (row + 1) * s,
          col * s: (col + 1) * s] = digit.numpy()

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
plt.imshow(image, cmap='Greys_r')
plt.axis('Off')
plt.savefig('asd.png')
plt.close()
```

Comment: At first glance the tutorial probably used SOTA initialization while you sample your starting weights from `[-1, 1]`. Initialization is a huge part of neural networks since gradient descent does descent search in a much larger space so a good starting point is pivotal. There are many papers and resource available online about initialization. I would suggest going to the tensorflow library initializers and reading the documentation aswell as looking up some theory about these methods.